# Velodyne point cloud node doesn't work

Tags: ros, lidar, velodyne-pointcloud, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a 32 HDl and VLP 16. I built the velodyne package by compiling it from source as I wanted to use VLP-16 driver.

When I try to run the velodyne pointcloud node for the HDL 32, I get the following error

```
$ rosrun velodyne_pointcloud cloud_node _calibration:=32db.yaml
[ INFO] [1458049427.031892132]: correction angles: 32db.yaml
YAML Exception: yaml-cpp: error at line 0, column 0: bad conversion
[ERROR] [1458049427.036928149]: Unable to open calibration file: 32db.yaml
[ INFO] [1458049427.043593822]: Reconfigure Request
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229102/velodyne-point-cloud-node-doesn%27t-work/) by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2016-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is apparently a bug caused by a recent source update affecting the YAML reader.

See [issue #84](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/issues/84).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-03-22**:
It's fixed now in the `master`source.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `YAML Exception` points to an error in the calibration file (the `YAML Execption`s are somtime not very descriptive, so you have to figure out "manually" what the problem actually is).

Either, this is misconfigured (missing tags, expecting different fields, even stupid whitespace errors are somtimes a problem) or the file is simply not there at all. This is what the `Unable to open calibration file` points to.

Keep in mind, that if you do a `rosrun`, the working directory is the directory where you execute this command. I.e. it is looking for `32db.yaml` in the directory you are currently.

(and as another option, it might also be a file permission problem)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on 2016-03-16**:
hi,

thanks. But i think it has to do something with the yaml-cpp version

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-03-18**:
What operating system are you running, and what version of `yaml-cpp` does it have?